# Flink apply vs process

Tags: apache-flink

Both functions of `WindowedStream`: `.apply` and `.process` has the same description. The only difference I've found was that: `.apply` receives `Context` whereas `.proccess` receives `Window`.

What should one consider when deciding between `apply` and `process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newer `process` method is passed a `Context`, which contains the `Window` and other useful fields. This subsumes the `apply` method, which is passed the `Window`. There is no good reason to use `apply`, it has simply been retained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hi David - I'm curious why `apply(WindowFunction)` (and maybe `WindowFunction` in general) been deprecated yet...seems like this decision was made a while ago.

Comment: Hi Ken - I don't know why apply and WindowFunction haven't been deprecated. But in general, the philosophy seems to be to deprecate things that are actively getting in the way, which isn't really the case here.